# Calculating co-variance in Python without Numpy or Stats modules

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics

I have been tasked with writing a function in python to calculate the covariance of an array, without using the numpy or statistics module.

I used the below to find the variance:

```
def daml_var(x):
    m = x.sum() / len(x)
    var = sum((x-m)**2 for x in x)/len(x)
    return var
```

However I am struggling with the co-variance formula! My below formula returns zero...don't know why. Any takers?

```
def daml_cov(x, y):
    m = x.sum() / len(x)
    m2 = y.sum()/len(y)
    xm = sum((x-m) for x in x)
    ym = sum((y-m2) for y in y)
    return xm*ym/len(x)
```

Thanks

Comment: *without Numpy*? looks like your inputs are numpy array, and why did you tag `numpy` :-)

Comment: Sorry! I should have been clearer. We were given numpy arrays and asked to find the co-variance without using the numpy statistical methods.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate `xm` (and `ym`) as the sum of all deviations from the mean. This number will always be zero, by definition of the mean.

Instead, you need to put the product `(x - m) * (y - m2)` inside the sum, and have the two `for` loops run in parallel. This can be done with the `zip()` function.

Also, you shouldn't use `x` (and `y`) for both the array and its items.

By the way, if you want to follow the standard convention for the sample variance and covariance, you should divide by `len(x) - 1` instead of `len(x)` in both cases. See the [Wikipedia article on the sample covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance).

In summary, this should work:

```py
def daml_cov(x, y):
    m = x.sum() / len(x)
    m2 = y.sum() / len(y)
    return sum([(xi - m) * (yi - m2) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]) / (len(x) - 1)
```

Comment: So we have to use these on array values which are float points. I used the below code and it returned an error.

`def daml_cov(x, y):
    m = x.sum() / len(x)
    m2 = y.sum()/len(y)
    for x in x:
        sum((x-m)*(y-m2))
        for y in y:
            sum((x-m)*(y-m2))
    return`

'numpy.float64' object is not iterable'

Comment: @Jimmy K Thanks for the feedback. I have expanded my answer.